# Sencha Touch filter list view data store

Tags: filter, sencha-touch, extjs

So I'm a Sencha Touch noob and I may have gotten in over my head. What I'm trying to do is filter data I have from one master list then drill down. So I've got my main list - Categories. When a category is selected a list of locations comes up. I'm having a problem getting my models to talk to each other (I think). As it stands right now if I select a category all of my data gets returned, where all I want is the selected category. I can filter my store using a property and a specified value. Is it possible to set the value as a variable that I pass from my category menu? I've been cr

Here is my code: Category.js

```
app.views.CategoryList = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
layout: 'card',
fullscreen: true,
scrolling: 'vertical',
initComponent: function() {
    //Check if device is a phone, if so only display the title since the viewport is smaller
     if (!Ext.is.Phone) {
            var listTemplate = '{post_type}';

      } else {
            var listTemplate = '{post_type}';

      }
    this.list = new Ext.List({
        grouped: false,
        indexBar: false,
        itemTpl: '{post_type}',
        store: app.stores.CategoryList,
        listeners: {
            selectionchange: {fn: this.onSelect, scope: this}
        }
    });

    ///selectionchange : function(){
       // this.store.filter('post_type', listTemplate)
        //this.onSelect('post_type')

    this.listpanel = new Ext.Panel({
        layout: 'fit',
        items: this.list,
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            title: listingTitle
        }],
        listeners: {
            activate: { fn: function(){
                this.list.getSelectionModel().deselectAll();
                Ext.repaint();
            }, scope: this }
        }
    });

    this.items = this.listpanel;

    app.views.CategoryList.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
},

onSelect: function(sel, records){
    if (records[0] !== undefined) {
            var categoryCard = new app.views.LocationsList({
                        store: app.stores.LocationList,
                        //store: app.stores.LocationList.filter('post_type',null),
                        prevCard: this.listpanel,
                        record: records[0]
                    });
                    this.setActiveItem(categoryCard, 'slide');


    }
}
});

Ext.reg('CategoryList', app.views.CategoryList);
```

LocationModel.js

```
//The model will load the locations information you entered in the locations.xml file         after it has been fed through JSON

//Register the Location Model
Ext.regModel('Locations', {
fields: [{name: 'post_title', type: 'string'},
         {name: 'post_type', type: 'string'}],
belongsTo: 'Category'
});
//Load XML data from JSON into local store
app.stores.LocationsList = new Ext.data.Store({
model: "Locations", //Model to use for the Store
/*filters: [
          {
              property: 'post_type',
              value: null
          }
      ],*/
sorters: [{
 property: 'post_title', //Set the title as a sorter to the listing card can use the grouped list layout
                direction: 'ASC'
            }],
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax', //Load JSON from our source defined in the config file
    url: HTTP_ROOT + '/' + JSON_SOURCE,
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'markers1'
    },

    id  : 'LocationsID'
},
getGroupString : function(record) {
    // return the first character of the address in order to group
    return record.get('post_title')[0];
},

listeners: {
    'load': function (t, r, s) {
        //Fire custom event once all the load is complete
        Ext.dispatch({
            controller: app.controllers.map,
            action: 'loaded',
            records: r
        });
    },
},
  autoLoad : true //We start loading the info into the datastore immediately after the app is started to make it available ASAP

});
```

CategoryModel.js

```
//The model will load the locations information you entered in the locations.xml file   after it has been fed through JSON

Ext.regModel('Category', {
fields: [
{name: 'post_type', type: 'string'},],
hasMany: {
    model: 'Locations',
    name : 'locations',
    filterProperty: 'post_type'
}
});

var data = {
"categories":[
{"post_type":"trails"},
{"post_type":"Adventure Guides"},
{"post_type":"brew"},
{"post_type":"Festivals and Races"},
{"post_type":"Paddle and Rafting"},
{"post_type":"Parks and Forests"},
{"post_type":"Campgrounds"},
{"post_type":"Rivers, Mountains, Lakes"}
]
};

//Load XML data from JSON into local store
app.stores.CategoryList = new Ext.data.Store({
model: "Category", //Model to use for the Store
data: data,
sorters: [{
                property: 'post_type', //Set the title as a sorter to the listing card can use the grouped list layout
                direction: 'ASC'
            }],
proxy: {
    type: 'memory', //Load JSON from our source defined in the config file
    //url: HTTP_ROOT + '/' + JSON_SOURCE, 
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'categories'
    },
    id  : 'CategoryID'
},
getGroupString : function(record) {
    // return the first character of the address in order to group
    return record.get('post_type')[0];
},

listeners: {
    'load': function (t, r, s) {
        //Fire custom event once all the load is complete
        Ext.dispatch({
            controller: app.controllers.map,
            action: 'loaded',
            records: r
        });
    },
},
autoLoad : true //We start loading the info into the datastore immediately after the app is started to make it available ASAP

});
```

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like you're in touch 1.1 which I'm now officially rusty in, but I'll give it a shot. My forays into using remotefilter always ended in tears so I ended up rolling my own rather than trying to use the built-in filter methods. YMMV.

You can grab the store and the store's proxy, then set an extraParams object, which gets translated into get parameters. You can also modify the url in this fashion. So in the past I've written custom setter methods to filter remote, because it just seemed to work better than the touch1.1 builtins.

You'd grab the store and pass your filter to a method like:

```
setFilterParams: function(param) {
  var p = this.getProxy();
  p.extraParams = {filter_value: param};
  // p.url also works
}

... 
yourstore.load();
```

So i.e. your main list uses onitemtap or selectionchange to find the record from the first (unfiltered) store, takes that value and applies to your setFilter on the second store that your detail page uses.

Also note, since you said you're a newb. Those stores represent singletons, so if you have two lists that use the same store, if list1 filters the data on the store that will affect list2.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you go about doing what you need (for two levels of filtering) in Sencha Touch 1.

//Models

```
App.models.States = Ext.regModel('State', {
  idProperty : 'stateId',
  fields : [
    { name : 'stateId', type : 'integer'},
    { name : 'state', type : 'string'}
  ]
});

App.models.Districts = Ext.regModel('District', {
  fields : [
    { name : 'districtId', type : 'integer'},
    { name : 'stateId', type : 'integer'},
    { name : 'district', type : 'string'}
  ]
});
```

//Stores

```
App.stores.StatesStore = new Ext.data.Store({
  model : 'State',
  data : [
    { stateId : 1, state : 'Maharashtra' },
    { stateId : 2, state : 'Andhra Pradesh' }
  ],
  sorters : 'state',
  autoLoad : true
});

App.stores.DistrictStore = new Ext.data.Store({
  model : 'State',
  data : [
    { districtId : 1, district : 'Nasik', stateId : 1 },
    { districtId : 2, district : 'Thane', stateId : 1 },
    { districtId : 3, district : 'Jalgaon', stateId : 1 },
    { districtId : 4, district : 'Hyderabad', stateId : 2 },
    { districtId : 5, district : 'Nizamabad', stateId : 2 },
    { districtId : 6, district : 'Kurnool', stateId : 2 }
  ],
  sorters : 'district',
  autoload : true
});
```

I've loaded data inline here, so that you can see how they are associated. Each district id has now been asscociated with a state id. For example, the district of Nasik, exists inside the state of Maharashtra. Therefore, districtID 1 for 'Nasik' is now associated with stateId 1 for 'Maharashtra'.

//For the Selectfield for States & Districts

```
{
 xtype: 'selectfield',
 name : 'state',
 id : 'state',
 label: 'State',
 store : App.stores.StatesStore,
 displayField : 'state',
 valueField : 'stateId',
 listeners : {
    change : function(t, value){
        Ext.dispatch({
            controller : 'Users',
            action : 'filterLocations',
            data : {value:value, level : 'district'}
        });
    }
 }
},
{
  xtype: 'selectfield',
  name : 'district',
  id : 'district',
  label: 'District',
  store : App.stores.DistrictStore,
  displayField : 'district',
  valueField : 'districtId'
}
```

Now the selectfields have been associated with the Models/Stores that we created earlier.

We will now look at the controller function called when the selectfield for States has been changed.

```
filterLocations: function(params){
    var value = params.data.value;
    var level = params.data.level;

    if(level == "district"){
        App.stores.DistrictStore.clearFilter();
        App.stores.DistrictStore.filter('stateId', value);
        var firstValue = Ext.getCmp('district').store.getAt(0);
        if(firstValue) Ext.getCmp('district').setValue('Select District');
    }
    else if(level == "block"){
        App.stores.BlockStore.clearFilter();
        App.stores.BlockStore.filter('districtId', value);
        var firstValue = Ext.getCmp('block').store.getAt(0);
        if(firstValue) Ext.getCmp('block').setValue('Select Block');
    }
},
```

I've given you an extended controller, where more than one level can be supported. For example, states would filter down districts, districts could filter down villages, etc etc. Therfore, in the controller we take in the level at which filtering need be done. If the filtering is to be done between states and districts, the first if condition would be called, and the district store (and therefore the selectfield) would be filtered down to get the desired values.

Comment: You can extend this model/store/controller concept to Sencha Touch 2 as well. I don't have ready example with me right now, but it should be relatively easy.